# A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of... that's perfect, but it DOES start with '['

Tags: android, json

This is very confusing, all of a sudden, the following code doesn't work. Trying to make my Android display what a web page already shows pretty well:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost;
          httppost = new HttpPost(myUrl);              
          try 
          {                
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              StringBuilder strResponse = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
              JSONArray arrWishlists = new JSONArray(strResponse.toString());
              .... 
              the rest is not important
```

It crashes at creating of the JSONArray with the following message, which would make a lot of sense if my array didn't in fact was a truly legal JSON array that works perfectly when used in javascript on the same page I'm trying to access from Android here:

```
03-30 02:55:21.304: W/System.err(346): org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of [{"Index":"296","Name":"\u041c\u0410\u0428\u0418\u041d\u042b","Description":"","VisibleToFriends":"1","Items":[{"Name":"porche 911","Description":"","Image":"http:\/\/www.tuningnews.net\/wallpaper\/1024x768\/porsche-911-carrera-s-coupe-01.jpg","Index":"0","Link":"http:\/\/www.autotrader.com\/research\/car-models\/2012-Porsche-911\/21675-336697-Coupe\/2dr-Cpe-S-Turbo~model.jsp","ReservedBy":"1225198689"},{"Name":"Ferrari","Description":"F150","Image":"http:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-szn3PGyHsC4\/TVPtm1Eh2HI\/AAAAAAAADiI\/58R4x_IaE9g\/s1600\/ferrari_f150_1680_8.jpg","Index":1,"Link":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Ferrari_150\u00b0_Italia","ReservedBy":"1374872217"},{"Name":"Lamborgini","Description":"Diablo","Image":"http:\/\/users1.ml.mindenkilapja.hu\/users\/ozdsuli\/uploads\/lamborgini.jpg","Index":2,"Link":"","ReservedBy":"1225198689"}]},{"Index":"341","Name":"Birthday","Description":"My birthday wishes","VisibleToFriends":"1","Items":[{"Name":"iPad 3 ","Description":"Need for speed","Image":"http:\/\/www.techieday.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2011\/05\/ipad-3-release-date.jpg","Index":"0","Link":"","ReservedBy":"1225198689"},{"Name":"iOS Development License","Description":"100$","Image":"http:\/\/www.geek.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2010\/09\/apps_20100901.jpg","Index":1,"Link":"http:\/\/developer.apple.com\/programs\/ios\/","ReservedBy":""}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing in inputStreamToString but try doing this

```
private String convertToString(InputStream istr){
    if( istr == null ){
        return "";
    }
    try {
        return new java.util.Scanner(istr).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And in your Http code

```
String strResponse = convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
JSONArray arrWishlists = new JSONArray(strResponse);
```

Comment: I'm using basically the same mechanism of converting a stream to String, but with StringBuilder. Tried your method just in case, but nope, didn't work. The thing about my code is that it worked perfectly until I changed the hosting provider. My guess is that the new one sends http response in some different encoding which breaks the JSON parser...